# Replace some values in a dataframe with NaN's if the index of the row does not exist in a multi-index object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a really large dataframe similar to this:

```
    Customer_Id   Day    Hour   Latitude   Longitude     
0.        a        dd     hh      x1         y1
1.        a        dd     hh'     x2         y2
2.        a        dd     hh'     x3         y3
3.        b        dd     hh'     x4         y4
```

And then I have an object (that I can convert into a DataFrame if necessary) with a sample per hour per day per customer of the latitude and longitude. However, Customer_Id, Day and Hour are all indices here whereas before they were not. It looks something like this:

```
                                 Latitude   Longitude
Customer_Id    Day     Hour
    a          dd       hh         x1         y1
               dd       hh'        x3         y3
    b          dd       hh'        x4         y4
```

Previously, I had two dataframes with only one index each (let's call them df1 for the first, which is the first dataframe here, and df2 for the second, which is the single index dataframe that I had instead of the second object) so I used:

```
df1['Latitude']= np.where((~df1.index.isin(df2.index)), np.nan, df1['Latitude'])
```

Previously this code worked but now under this new scenario it returns this error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I have tried to change the code accordingly but it's not working. Could someone take a look at this?

Comment: That's a warning, not an error: your code might still be doing what you intend it to do. How exactly are you creating and modifying `df1`? There might be a line somewhere like `df1 = df1[boolean_mask]`. Adding `.copy()` to such a line (turning it into `df1 = df1[boolean_mask].copy()`) might avoid the warning.

Comment: What is your expected output with `np.where`, because the operation your doing now, does not make sense. Especially since you're comparing a dataframe index with an aggregated index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset your index with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1['Latitude']= np.where((~df1.index.isin(df2.reset_index().index)), np.nan, df1['Latitude'])

print(df1)
  Customer_Id Day Hour Latitude Longitude
0           a  dd   hh       x1        y1
1           a  dd  hh'       x2        y2
2           a  dd  hh'       x3        y3
3           b  dd  hh'      NaN        y4
```

**What does reset_index do**?
It converts the indices back to columns:

```
print(df2.reset_index())
  Customer_Id Day Hour Latitude Longitude
0           a  dd   hh       x1        y1
1           a  dd  hh'       x3        y3
2           b  dd  hh'       x4        y4
```